# How to take trace over group and Dirac indices?

Tags: mathematical-physics, eigenvalue, dirac-matrices, trace

I'm currently reading Pokorski's book "[Gauge Field Theories](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511612343)" and in Chapter 13 he discusses, among other things, [Fujikawa's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujikawa_method) of deriving the chiral current (see page 488 and the following).

For the following, let $\varphi_n(x)$ be a basis of eigenfunctions of the operator $i\not D$. We can then write
$$\begin{gather*}
\psi = \sum_n a_n \varphi_n(x),\qquad \bar\psi=\sum_n\varphi^\dagger_n(x)\bar b_n,\qquad i\not D\varphi_n(x)=\lambda_n\varphi_n(x),
\end{gather*}$$
where the $a_n$ and $\bar b_n$ are Grassmanian numbers.

In his derivation, he introduces a gauge-invariant regulator to calculate the Jacobian of the chiral transformation. Eq. (13.129) then says
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\int \mathrm{d}^{4} x \Theta(x) \sum_{n} \varphi_{n}^{\dagger}(x) \gamma_{5} \varphi_{n}(x) \\
\quad 
\equiv \lim _{M \rightarrow \infty} \int \mathrm{d}^{4} x \Theta(x) \sum_{n} \varphi_{n}^{\dagger}(x) \gamma_{5} \varphi_{n}(x) \exp \left(-\lambda_{n}^{2} / M^{2}\right) \\
\quad
\overset{(1)}{=}
\lim _{M \rightarrow \infty} \int \mathrm{d}^{4} x \Theta(x) \sum_{n} \widetilde{\operatorname{Tr}}\left[\gamma_{5} \exp \left[-(\mathrm{i} \not D)^{2} / M^{2}\right] \varphi_{n}(x) \varphi_{n}^{\dagger}(x)\right] \\
\quad
\overset{(2)}{=}\lim _{M \rightarrow \infty} \int \mathrm{d}^{4} x \Theta(x) \lim _{y \rightarrow x}\left\{\gamma_{5} \exp \left[-\left(\mathrm{i} \not D_{x}\right)^{2} / M^{2}\right]\right\}_{k l}^{a b} \sum_{n}\left[\varphi_{n}(x)\right]_{l}^{b}\left[\left(\varphi_{n}^{*}(y)\right]_{k}^{a}\right. ,
\end{array}
\end{equation}$$
where $\widetilde{\operatorname{Tr}}$ "means the trace over group and Dirac indices."

### Questions

- I don't understand the definition of $\widetilde{\operatorname{Tr}}$. What exactly does it mean to take the trace over the group and Dirac indices? Can someone give a simple example?
- In step $(2)$ I'm completely lost on the indices... Why exactly do the eigenfunctions have two indices besides the label $n$? Why does "the matrix" $\gamma^5 e^{-(i\not D)^2/M^2}$ have four indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heat kernel has four discrete indices in addition to the two continous space indices $x$,$y$  because the gamma matrices have  two: $\gamma^{ab}$;  and the matrix-valued gauge fields $A_\mu$'s that hide in the Dirac operator  have  two: $[A_\mu]_{kl}$. The heat kernel  is therefore an operator acting on  $L^2[{\mathbb R}^4]\otimes S\otimes V$ where $L^2[{\mathbb R}^4]$ is the Hilbert space of square integrable functions,  $S$ is the spinor space, and $V$ the gauge-group representation space.  To take the trace over the group one sets the group indices equal, $k=l$, and sums, similarly the spinor indices. later you will take the trace over $L^2[{\mathbb R}^4]$ by setting $x=y$ and integrating over ${\mathbb R}^4$

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer! I will have to think about this for a second, but just to be sure: $\exp(-(i\not D)^2/M^2)$ in line $(1)$ is only acting on $\varphi_n(x)$, right?

Comment: It's written very badly. I think  he means $\varphi_n^\dagger(x) e^{-(iD)^2/M^2} \varphi_n(x)$. I'd get another book.  You might also look at my lecture notes http://people.physics.illinois.edu/stone/lichnerowicz.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link to your lecture notes, will take a closer look at them!

Comment: When you write $\mathrm{tr}(\Gamma_5 e^{-t \not D{}^\dagger D})$ in your lecture notes, do you take the trace over the entire space $L^2[\mathbb{R}^4]\otimes S\otimes V$ at once, i.e. you include the $\langle x\vert \cdot\vert x \rangle $ operation?

Comment: I try to alway use ${\rm tr}$ (lower case t) for the discrete indices and ${\rm Tr}$ (upper case T) for the trace over both discrete indices and the function-space $x$ $y$. This is quite a common convention. If I have been inconsistent anywhere, I am sorry.